# Array referenced to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with **autofilter** in Excel macro. I have recorded the macro to autofilter my list. What i'm trying to accomplish is:

1. user will input the several names in separate sheet (ex. Worksheet #1)
2. macro will do is filter the list located in Worksheet #2 according to the names the user inputs.

Basically, i cannot use the code below because the list in the array will be different according to the user input.

Is that possible? Can you make any changes to my code?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$786").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "a.plegaria", "anna-marie.madrid", "annie-kaye.violante", "ayla-marie.pascual", _
        "beda-jr.jacob"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: your question is a bit unclear... how many sheets are there in your workbook? where you have data? etc... one tip- try to use `Advanced filter` which could be a better solution in such situation. Macro recorder will be helpful, too.

Comment: I have 2 worksheet. worksheet 1 contains list of names. worksheet 2 contains the table.

i've tried the macro recorder and the result is the above code. Unfortunately, the array display specific names. what if the user inputs a different name?

Comment: therefore I suggest it again- try with `Advanced filter` (not `AutoFilter`) which provide more options including wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

for instance

```
   Dim rData                  As Range
   Dim vCriteria

   Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F786")

   vCriteria = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value)
   rData.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=vCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```